# How to check age of a pull request of a repository in github

Tags: java, git, github, github-api

I am using Github v3 api, through that I want list of all existing Pull Request of a repository. Along with list of existing Pull Request, I want to get age of each pull request (how many days before Pull Request was created). I want to get all these details from my java project, how can I achieve this requirement using Github v3 api?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli) installed locally, you might consider calling (included from your Java program) [`gh pr list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list), which includes an "age" column.

To get the creation date (added in [`gh` 2.14.5, Aug. 2022](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.14.5))

```
gh pr list --jq '.items[].createdAt'
```